# _entities.SaveChange() error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm working on an intranet, the user can create a new Employee that contains his information (Name, Login, Password etc.) with the following :

```
 if (_service.Create(objEmployee))
        {
            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(objEmployee.Login, objEmployee.Password); // Creates the account as we create the Employee (form authentication)
            return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Index"));
        }
```

Once it enters Create and checks the information, it has to save it all with :

```
public Employee Create(Employee objEmployee)
    {
        _entities.AddToEmployees(objEmployee);
        _entities.SaveChanges(); // Fails here
        return objEmployee;
    }
```

And I get the following error :

```
An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
```

objEmployee contains all the information about the Employee and I can't figure why the saving fails. (And how to access the inner exception)

Here's the information I found :

```
    System.Data.UpdateException was caught
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
  Source=System.Data.Entity
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
       at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges()
       at CRAWebSiteMVC.Models.EntityEmployeeManagerRepository.Create(Employee objEmployee) in c:\Users\kade\Source\Workspaces\InfoCubedProjects\CRA\CRAWebSiteMVC\Models\Employee\EntityEmployeeManagerRepository.cs:line 17
       at CRAWebSiteMVC.Models.EmployeeManagerService.Create(Employee objEmployee) in c:\Users\kade\Source\Workspaces\InfoCubedProjects\CRA\CRAWebSiteMVC\Models\Employee\EmployeeManagerService.cs:line 79
  InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
       HResult=-2146232060
       Message=Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Password', table 'CRAV34.dbo.Employee'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
       Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
       ErrorCode=-2146232060
       Class=16
       LineNumber=1
       Number=515
       Procedure=""
       Server=MMSDEVNEW\SQL2008
       State=2
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
            at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
       InnerException:
```

Please note that this is the model for Password :

```
 public partial class Employee
{       
    public global::System.String Password
    {
        get
        {
            return _Password;
        }
        set
        {
            OnPasswordChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("Password");
            _Password = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false);
            ReportPropertyChanged("Password");
            OnPasswordChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.String _Password;
    partial void OnPasswordChanging(global::System.String value);
    partial void OnPasswordChanged();

}
```

Since the model created by Entity Framework was partial, I decided to create another partial class with the same name containing Password.

Comment: `InnerException` is a property on the `Exception` class.

Comment: And what does the Inner Exception's details say?

Comment: The message is self explanatory - _Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Password'_

Comment: But Password has a value at all times.

Comment: Is `objEmployee.Password` property inside `Create()` method is `null`  ?

Comment: No, it still has the value imputed in the Password box. EDIT : added information about Password

Comment: @Aruixe well, it's possible that if object you're saving to db has all its properties set then database context must have some *other* object that has password property value set to `null`.